# Django-formwizard and ModelFormSet save

Tags: python, django, django-views, formwizard, django-formwizard

I am rewriting a big piece of our application which requires a user to create a `Project` with `Rewards` attached to it.

The form is broken into different steps, the first two are the normal `Project`, the next one is the `Rewards`, and then lastly a simple preview that lets the user flick back and forth to create a perfect `Project`.

**my forms.py**

```
class BaseRewardFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseRewardFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Reward.objects.none()

RewardFormSet1 = modelformset_factory(Reward, extra=2, exclude=('project'), formset=BaseRewardFormSet)

class ProjectForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    """docstring for ProjectForm1"""
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude=( ... )

class ProjectForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    """docstring for ProjectForm2"""
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ( ... )
```

**my urls.py**

```
instance_dict = {'2': Reward.objects.none()}
url(r'^new-project/$', login_required(ProjectWizard.as_view([ProjectForm1, ProjectForm2, RewardFormSet1, ProjectForm3], instance_dict=instance_dict))),
```

**my views.py**

```
class ProjectWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = cloudfiles_storage

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectWizard, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
        initial_dict = self.get_form_initial('0')
        if self.steps.current == '1':
            step1_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
            context.update({'step1_data':step1_data,'currency_sign':step1_data['base_currency']})
        else:
            step1_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
            step2_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('1')
            step3_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('2')
            context.update({'step1_data':step1_data,'step2_data':step2_data,'step3_data':step3_data,})
        return context

    def get_template_names(self):
        step = int(self.steps.current)
        if step == 3:
            return 'formwizard/preview.html'
        else:
            return 'formwizard/wizard_form.html'

    def done(self, form_list, *args, **kwargs):
        form_data = form_list[0].cleaned_data
        form_data_details = form_list[1].cleaned_data
        form_data.update(form_data_details)
        project = Project()
        for field in project.__dict__.iterkeys():
            if field in form_data:
                project.__dict__[field] = form_data[field]
        project.owner = self.request.user
        project.date_published = datetime.now()
        project.save()        
        return render_to_response('formwizard/done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

when rendering redirect, it shows that all the data has been cleaned which means that the form is valid, and all the project data is saved to **Project**

I can see that the Rewards data will not save since it has not been called, but every solution I have tried thus far has failed.

**How can I implement Rewards into this solution on save?**

Maybe someone can shed some light on this, much appreciated!

Comment: @Rohan Edited the question in, at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this working? Assuming `Reward` has `project`.

```
for rw in form_list[2].save(commit=False):
    rw.project = project
    rw.save()
```

Comment: That solution ended up working, I over thought the whole process :(