# How to use `get_cleaned_data_for_step` method in a SessionWizardView?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am having an issue with persisting data from one page to the next in a SessionWizardView on my production server. It works fine on my local machine but I kept getting an `Exception Value: list index out of range` error when I tried to access the value of the list on a subsequent page.

As a result I am trying to use the `get_cleared_data_for_step` method but with no success.

**My current views.py**

```
PATH_ONE_IMAGES =   ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg', 'P4D4.jpg', 'P5D5.jpg']

class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10']:
            step = int(self.steps.current)

            if step in (5, 6, 7):
                image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)   
                images.insert(step - 5, image)        
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image

            elif step == 8:                          
                images[0] = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(5)
                images[1] = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(6)
                images[2] = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(7)     

                print 'This is your first image', images[0]
                print 'This is your second image', images[1]
                print 'This is your third image', images[2]
```

**Current outcome**

```
This is your first image None
This is your second image None
This is your third image None
```

**Expected outcome (sample)**

```
This is your first image P1D1.jpg
This is your second image P3D3.jpg
This is your third image P4D4.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong? I can find very little info on how to implement the `get_cleaned_data_for_step` method online except for these two SO questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612603/django-formwizard-and-modelformset-save), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860392/django-formwizards-how-to-painlessly-pass-user-entered-data-between-forms) and going by these my implementation looks like it should work.

[What annoys me most is that my previous solution works fine on my local machine but does not work in production.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081091/deployed-django-project-giving-list-index-out-of-range-error-local-project-wo?noredirect=1#comment42672558_27081091)

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Deepend

Comment: How do you pass data to the form in step 5? Do you provide it manually or do you use some initial data?

Comment: On step 5 the only data added to the form is the `image` e.g. P1D1.jpg. This is generated by `random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)` the value of which I then save into a list (step 5 - `images[0], step 6 - `images[1], step 7 - images[2]). I then want to access this list and its values on step 8 so I can re-display whichever images where shown to the user. Does that answer your question?